# python bitwise operators give different result with binary numbers and ints

Tags: python, python-3.x

Depending on how I specify my input numbers, I get a different result with bitwise operators:

```py
>>> 208 == 0b11010000
True
>>> 208       & 0b0111000
16
>>> 0b1101000 & 0b0111000
40
```

This is both python2 and python3, and not impacted when I add parenthesis.

Has anyone an explanation ? I kind of doubt this is a bug, seeing at it exists in both versions, but maybe...

Comment: `0b1101000` is not the same number as `0b11010000`.

Comment: Obviously... after you pointed it out. I swear I looked at it for quite long time without noticing. The bug in my code must be elsewhere, thanks !

Comment: ```0b0111000``` != ```0b11010000```